# ipython notebook bokeh and output_notebook

Tags: python, bokeh

What is happening when I get the following error? There is no error from within the notebook. But when I do this in regular iPython I'm wondering what is happening.... and what `In:` means... see error below.... (last 5 lines)

```
#set up domain and function with max
x = np.linspace(lower, upper, steps)
y = func(x)
y_max = np.amax(y) * 1.1

output_notebook()

p = figure(
   tools="pan,box_zoom,reset,save",
   y_range=[0, y_max], title="Some Beta Distributions",
   x_axis_label='days', y_axis_label='value'
)

p.line(x, y, legend = "pdf", line_color="blue")

show(p)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/path.py:303: UserWarning: IPython dir
 '/home/vagrant/.ipython' is not a writable location, using a temp directory.
  " using a temp directory.".format(ipdir))
In :
In :
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`In:` is the standard ipython prompt. It is `ipython`'s way of telling you that it is waiting for input (just like `>>>` in the standard python interpreter).

Note that `output_notebook` will only function in the browser (i.e., in the notebook). If you want to run code in a command line ipython shell (I am assuming that is what you mean by "in regular iPython") then you will have to use `output_file` or one of the functions in `bokeh.embed`.

Comment: what is an example of the input I can put in this command?  I am just interested in what it will create... I will also check out `bokeh.embed`, thanks.

Comment: It's a python interpreter prompt (not the default one, but that's what it is). You can input anything you would input into the standard python interpreter (i.e., python code).

Comment: I am assuming Ipython wants me to put something specific there like a location but I do not know the syntax. No need to respond, I just thought Python wants me to put something specific like a filepath in.

Answer (score 0):

It means that for whatever reason, your account does not have permission to modify the contents of the `.ipython` folder, which IPython uses to store some settings and cache some data, so IPython will create and use a temporary directory instead.

To fix this, you should either modify the permissions on the `.ipython` folder from the command line and give yourself read/write permissions, or modify the `IPYTHON_DIR` environment variable to point to a folder you *do* have permissions for.

Or, if you don't feel like fixing the error + don't mind that IPython is using a temp folder, don't do anything.

Comment: but there is no number next to `In:`... I am assuming Ipython wants me to put something specific there like a location but I do not know the syntax.